# django type object 'PoliceDefenceJobs' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python, django

Here is my models.py

```
class PoliceDefenceJobs(models.Model):
    police_defence_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    start_date        = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    last_date         = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    post_name         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    education         = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    more_info         = models.TextField()
    requirement_board = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type              = models.IntegerField()
    job_id            = models.IntegerField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)
    join_id           = models.IntegerField(default=None,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Police Defence Jobs"
```

here is my views.py

```
class PoliceDefenceJobs:
    def police_defence_jobs(request):
        PoliceDefenceJobs.objects.all().delete()
        return JsonResponse({"code":200})
```

Here i am getting type object 'PoliceDefenceJobs' has no attribute 'objects'
error..

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: Did you define a form, view, etc. with the same name?

Comment: no.. there is no for only view and model

Comment: no template also

Comment: Did you define another manager on `PoliceDefenceJobs`? Did you add the app to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes it is in installed app.. there in one model in this name

Comment: Can you possibly show the import statement you used? Also are you able to otherwise retrieve objects, through shell for example?

Comment: from .models import PoliceDefenceJobs

Comment: It is working in shell

Answer (score 0):

Your class `PoliceDefenceJobs` in your views is clashing with your model `PoliceDefenceJobs`.

Normally I would suggest that you rename the class in your views, but in your case, the class in your view looks very strange. That's not how you do class based views in Django. The easiest thing to do is to delete the class and move the method outside of it:

```
def police_defence_jobs(request):
    ...
    return JsonResponse({"code":200})
```

You might then have to update your URL patterns to reference your new view.